# How to automatically add a role to a new guild member when they join a Discord guild

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been trying for a quite a while to make a bot that should automatically give a certain role to any new user that joins my discord server and so far I haven't had any luck.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  console.log('User ' + member.user.username + ' has joined the server!')
  var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Alive and Clean');
  member.addRole(role)
});
```

I have encounted an error that is `TypeError: member.addRole is not a function`.

Comment: A recent version of Discord.JS has introduced a lot of changes and managers that will break code from older tutorials and videos assuming you're on the latest version. It sounds like you want [guildMemberRoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add)

Comment: @Gavin does that mean that it is not .addRole but because of the recent version change it is just .add(*insert role here*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since discord.js v12 you now need to use `roles.add()` instead of `addRole()`.

Comment: So like this?

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  console.log('User ' + member.user.username + ' has joined the server!')
  var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Alive and Clean');
  member.roles.add(*role*)
});

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I tried 'member.roles.add(role)'

Comment: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
Though it has administrator activated on the server

Comment: The bot's role needs to be above the role you're giving to the user in the role settings

Comment: Yeah I realized that too just a moment ago and it fixed it. Thanks for your help mate :D